# ImageMagick convert gif with transparency problem

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, gif

I wrote a script to add watermark to images on my site. Everything works ok for png/jpg, but gif images must be treaten by more complicated way. My script:

```
convert -splice x36 -gravity south -background white image.gif \
-coalesce -gravity SouthEast -geometry +0+0 -background white \
null: watermark-text.png -layers composite new-image.gif
```

For 95 percent of gif it works fine. But there are some examples, that brings errors.
Concern this image:
[image]

Normal cat. Only first frame contains background (viewed layers in gimp).

[image]

This is not normal cat. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you include `watermark-text.png` as well, it will make it easier to people to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `-splice` is being applied relative to the gif's frames' layout rather than the complete image's layout.  Do the `-coalesce` first (order matters):

```
convert -coalesce -splice x36 -gravity south -background white image.gif \
-gravity SouthEast -geometry +0+0 -background white \
null: watermark-text.png -layers composite new-image.gif
```

See "[Simple Modifications of Animations](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#draw)" from the [*Examples of ImageMagick Usage*](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

*The following switch sequence worked for me:*

```
magick convert input.gif -coalesce -gravity south -background white -splice x100 -gravity southeast -geometry +5+5 -background white null: watermark-text.png -layers composite -bordercolor black -border 1 output.gif
```

[image]